# Function to check if number is stepping returns false

Tags: python

I've written a function to check if a number is *stepping*: each consecutive digit differs from the last by exactly 1.

```
def isStep(num):
    num = str(num)
    prevDigit = int(num[0])-1

    for i in str(num):
        if (int(i)-1 == prevDigit or int(i)+1 == prevDigit):
            prevDigit = i
            continue
        else:
            print(int(i)-1, prevDigit)
            return False

    return True
```

I've tried it for the number `1234`. For some reason, it returns `False` when it gets to the second digit, thinking 2-1 does not equal 1. (See the print statement in the else).

Why is this? Is there a bug in my code somewhere that's causing this?

Comment: The problem is that `i` is a string. Change `prevDigit = i` to `prevDigit = int(i)`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Another way to calculate this is to subtract the number from the same number shifted one digit to the right (and disregarding the first and last digits)

```
1232     (a)
 1232    (b)
-----
_111_    (abs(a-b) per digit)
```

by subtract I here mean the absolute difference `abs(2-1)==1`, `abs(3-2)==1`, and `abs(2-3)==1` (i.e. differ by 1, either up or down).

In Python this would look like:

```
def isStep(n):
    a = map(int, str(n)[1:])   # convert to a list of integer digits
    b = map(int, str(n)[:-1])
    return all(abs(a_digit - b_digit) == 1 for a_digit, b_digit in zip(a, b))
```